# What is the convergence or divergence for $\sqrt[n]{1+c_n}$

Tags: calculus

If we have $\sqrt[n]{1+c^n}$ where $c\in (0,1)$ for all $n\in N$ is posible to rewrite $c=\frac{1}{a}$ tnen $c^n=\frac{1}{a^n}$ were $ a\in (1,\infty)$, then we can write

$$\sqrt[n]{1+c_n}=\sqrt[n]{1+\frac{1}{a_n}}=\sqrt[n]{\frac{a_n+1}{a_n}},$$

now 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_n+1}{a_n}=1$$
then
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{\frac{a_n+1}{a_n}}=1$$
Do you think this procedure is good?

Comment: How do you know that $\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{a_n +1}{a_n} =1$. Do you know that $a_n$ increases an $n$ increases from somewhere?

Comment: why do you think $\lim \frac{a_n+1}{a_n}=1$?

Comment: $c^n$ or $c_n$ ?

Answer (score 3):

No. We have $1 \le \sqrt[n]{1+c_n} \le \sqrt[n]{2}$.

Hence $\sqrt[n]{1+c_n} \to 1$ for $n \to \infty$

Answer (score 1):

No, as far as we know, we can not conclude that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_n+1}{a_n}=1.$$ However, if $\{a_n\}_{n\geq 1}$ is any sequence contained in $[m, M]$ with $0<m\leq M$, then, as $n\to+\infty$,
$$1=e^0\leftarrow\exp\left(\frac{\ln(m)}{n}\right)=\sqrt[n]{m}\leq \sqrt[n]{a_n}\leq\sqrt[n]{M}=\exp\left(\frac{\ln(M)}{n}\right)\to e^0=1$$
which implies that  $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{a_n}=1$.